# Why is Wi-Fi not working on Ubuntu 16.04 in HP Notebook?

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, intel-wireless

I have dual boot on my laptop and Wi-Fi is working fine on Windows 10 but I am not even getting Wi-Fi available connections on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried so many online solutions in the past 1 week but nothing worked. Please help to troubleshoot.

***Note:*** LAN is working fine.

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011992/wifi-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04) solution too, but did not work.

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` command is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel modules: wl
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: added. It is: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10) DeviceName: WLAN Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110] Kernel modules: wl 0: hci0: Bluetooth Soft blocked: yes Hard blocked: no

Comment: `sudo lshw -C network | grep -iA5 wireless` would be useful.

Comment: I executed this command and rebooted the system but it didn't work.

Comment: Install Ubuntu 18.04 and it will work

Comment: Okay doing it :)

Comment: You misunderstood. Wasn't supposed to be a direct fix. I wanted to see the output for that.  16.04 works ok with wifi.

Comment: Everything is working on Ubuntu 18. Thanks  :)